# MQ JNDI exception if the qmanager jndi is defined in multiple tomcat context.xml

Tags: tomcat, jms, jndi, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have 2 applications deployed in the same tomcat jvm. Each application have their own context.xml:
- app1.xml
- app2.xml
In each of the app*.xml, I have MQ jndi resource defined:

```
<!-- JMS configuration FOR MQSeries - The connection factory -->
 <Resource
      name="jms/JMSQueueConnectionFactory"
      auth="Container"
      type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
      factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
      description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
      CCDTURL="file:///apps/mqm_opt/creds/AMQCLCHL_XA.TAB"
      QMGR="***Example***QM01***Example***" UCP="Y"/>
```

I dont have MQ or jms jars in any of my wars. They are on the MQ client installation. I have added then in the classpath using shared.loader of catalina.properties:

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/*.jar,/opt/mqm/java/lib/*.jar
```

Each application with just fine when deployed separately. But when they are deployed together in the same jvm, I am getting a null pointer at startup of one of the applications:

```
Jul 29, 2015 6:15:14 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:176)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:286)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:76)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
```

So The app1 works fine but the app2 fails with the above exception. I have generally noticed this kind of error is when we have class loading issues. But in this case, I am not able to figure out where the issue is. Any clue will help.

EDIT: After some testing I figured, if tomcat loads app1 first then both of the apps work fine. But if it pick app2 then there is a problem. It seems like app2 is loading MQ classes with a wrong class loader. Not sure why. I have checked the war. It does not contain the MQ classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last edit gave me the clue. Upon careful inspection, I realised I had some MQ jar/classes packaged in app2.war. That is why when app2.war loaded first, it would load using WebApp2 class loader and This class is not accessible by app1.war. That is why the app1 would fail to load. 
While app1.war did not have any mq classes. So when app1 loads first, the MQ classes were loaded by System class loader which is accessible by both apps.
Solution obviously was removing mq jars from app2.war

Answer (score 0):

Based on notes in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Using_resources I would suggest the resource in TomCat
should be along these lines.

```
<Resource name="jms/MyJMSCF" auth="Container"
          type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory"
          factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
          hostName="my.host.name"
          transportType="1"/>  <!-- 1 means client mode -->
```

The MQConnectionFactory should be a compatible bean-style object; there are lots of configuration options - full JavaDoc is
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnectionFactory.html

The com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory object is solely used by JNDI to re-inflate an  object store via the javax.naming.Referencable interface.

Comment: I am not sure how this solves the problem mentioned above. I am using tomcat7. Also, the configuration above is the recommended way for defining IBM MQ connection factory.